# Hungarian Algorithm for Rank n Tensor

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

The **Hungarian Algorithm** is used for the assignment problem on a matrix (or rank 2 tensor). **I'm wondering if there is an extension for higher rank tensors**. So for example, if each worker is assigned to one task but can additionally choose from different tools to fulfill them (hence rank 3), with each tool existing only once.

Clearly there should be perfect matching with minimal cost so it is **not**, in this case, 3-partite matching (which would have 9 vertices and therefore no perfect matching). It is more like some pairwise perfect matching of minimal cost between complete bipartite graphs (worker-task, worker-tool, tool-task). But one cannot really untangle these three like that.

If it exists, where do I find further literature on that specifically and which polynomial time complexity does the problem posess?

Thank you so much in advance.

Best
Interstedbutnotknowing